# Converter tempo do vídeo html5 em horas, minutos e segundos - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vídeo, conversão, reprodutor-de-video

Preciso de uma ajudinha, sou novo aqui e estou tentando criar um player de vídeo personalizado, só que estou tento dificuldades na parte do tempo, e eu queria que alguém me ajudasse a fazer só isso, se possível, demarcando e explicando um pouquinho, só queria saber com converter o tempo do vídeo pra dar um "span" em horas, minutos e segundos, no momento a unica base que tenho é isso (bem pouco kk):

Comment: Bem-vindo, você poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/254630/edit) sua pergunta e colocar o código do que você já tentou fazer ?

Comment: é possível fazer isso com uma mácara/filtro em javascript, vários frameworks oferecem isso.

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo simples com AngularJS

```
<html ng-app="helloWorld">
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <!-- Biblioteca AngularJS -->
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("helloWorld", []);
        angular.module("helloWorld").controller("helloWorldCtrl", function ($scope) {
            <!-- Para teste usei o new Date() para pegar a data atual -->
            $scope.message = new Date();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="helloWorldCtrl">
        <!-- variável | máscara -->
        {{message | date: 'hh:mm:ss'}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```